# Crash on boost::posix_time::from_time_t when compile with -ftrapv

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, integer-overflow

I use function `ptime from_time_t(time_t t);` and set `t` with big values like as UINT_MAX.
When i use `-ftrapv` option - program crashes because happens signed overflow, without option - sometimes result is not correct(near 00:00, Jan 1 1970).
I don't want to disable `-ftrapv` option.

Question:
Is it boost bug or `from_time_t` has some restricts on parameter?

Code [example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/lykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CIWGRLDFxCXaYDulCBEzEBJk%2BfgEVVQI1dQSFEdGx8ba19Y3Z5YNdoT0lfVwAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQma25RqCkEAPToTASYAPqObKe5eKq3ePePz3eYAHQIiYn72BMGgAgutNttMHsDltXoQFACgaCzBsGFsvLt9m4CABPRI3AjEJhwhEgxGhAg7FhEhgQGZ7ADsFh2zL2IJZO1oAmAO3JHKpqhMjKCAHlwgBxa4AWWBAA1BQARfZWNksrwMVLAMLoHmCHY%2BJgCxlyACS4QAKlLZQqlYj2baWQoCOgQCgFgRMR6zGYOvUofK9l6PQdaPyg25Hc6QK5aDaVcyIy60F53QdPWYEyA8AprgpWDcAG6Yz63Ugcrk6lPYP0Bsz25lhjNZnN5ouvfGlzlGCsAl35sReTANp0u6Ox4HsgnYhlMll19k7DNJilho4nF3vF5sF1UYioFib/EQfWqGZDyOjtYz%2Btx%2BeLt1QtyY1eO9cpJ4H7e7/fFggQEMG09UwODMLyvVlx1nelFRvUQCGQBAIDQdUKRA1RlkSfIGHMAA2HZMFPG9BWVCCHWHV1kzDcwzEwNDMAw9I8OrKiw2%2BAB3BBLlpM8RwYdAY0vWdCKguc7wooDHy9AAxUIswQZjxJA3j%2BKvRFrRBDg5loTgAFZeD8DgtFIVBOAkqxLAXBYlkhdYeFIAhNA0uYAGsQEkAAOL5tOwtYAE5sLc7D/MkDR6TWBItI4SQ9IcozOF4BQQA0OyHLmOBYBgRBXRYRI6FichKDQbLcriYAuDMBIaFoK5iASiAohiqJQjqbEYsKthBGFBhaBagzeCwKkjHEXrSHwYhKkcfNMAS4aaMqZMVkM8lMAiwzaDwKJCWIbEPCwGKCVeFK%2BAMYAFAANTwTBWOFPF9Ns/hBBEMR2CkGRBEUFR1GG3RwsMYxrGsfR1oS2BmC3Z8CFISa4m4ekfMcoz6IEaaAFoqAJJhEnzeLlvG9IXF44Y/ASYIJmKUocjfTDCYpvJ0m6MnplsHG2gYH0Gk8Jo9FaTC2fp3oygGTpqdGTo%2BamMo5gUSzlj0AlMBWHhNJ06LhuMjhVAC5HsMkHZgGQZAdjKr4uB2CBTIBnZcEIEgAzC0sPCK%2BhiFt2ZeHs3qZmc1yuC%2BfzyvpbD6TcyQuECrz9E4KLSBYEAvK%2BYPsJ87SNG0rgg7WbDtJ80h9MMtX4sS5KPdINLMrdRJk3yiBMHwIhiDwZ0KtkR7xBe%2B75CUNQYu%2B0hWMJRJDoi3Sc5itXhWTCuKVQKgdg17CtZ1vWDaNk2zb3HKnZdmY3ZSuYEEwJgsDiWkI8i3gY8kNZje0tYNEkHz3PK7yQ5H1W4tsQv3a0T3SBc1OvkvthDQYU1hhSzmYROp81gqzzu/L%2B8MIpmBgbwfORdv5zChqkZwkggA%3D%3D%3D)

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <climits>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {    
    long int lmax{LONG_MAX};
    unsigned int umax{UINT_MAX};
    
    std::cout<<"Start = "<<lmax<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"std::is_same_v<time_t, long int> = "
    <<std::is_same<time_t, long int>::value<<std::endl;
    try {    
        std::cout <<boost::posix_time::from_time_t(umax)<<std::endl;    
        std::cout <<boost::posix_time::from_time_t(lmax)<<std::endl;    
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
     std::cout<<"exception e = "<<e.what()<<std::endl;   
    }
    std::cout<<"Finish"<<std::endl;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there are undocumented "implicit" limits (preconditions) on the input to `from_time_t`:

The input causes signed integer overflow: 9223372036854775807 * 1000000 cannot be represented in type 'long int' in boost/date_time/time_resolution_traits.hpp:153:47 (boost 1.79).

In short if you *need* `trapv` you should probably avoid calling `from_time_t` with invalid arguments. You can raise an issue with the library developers to point out the lack of documentation. They'll probably reply with "but that's implentation/platform dependent", but if you give them your use-case, they could be compelled by documenting a "portably safe" input domain for `time_t`.